# Eigenvalues for the double-well potential

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, eigenfunctions

I am trying to find eigen-values, $E$, for the following differential operator:
$$\left[ -\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2}{dx^2} +L\left(x^2-a^2\right)^2\right]y(x) = E\,y(x) $$

where $L,a$ are two positive real parameters, given the boundary conditions that $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}y(x)=0$. I am only looking for eigenvalues which are smaller than $La^4$.

What I have tried:

Plug in a power series $y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\alpha_n(x-a)^n$ and get a recurrence relation on the coefficients:
\begin{align}
\alpha_2 &= -2E\alpha_0 \\
\alpha_3 &= -\frac{1}{3}E\alpha_1 \\
\alpha_4 &= -\frac{1}{3}(E^2-2La^4)\alpha_0 \\
\alpha_5 &= (-\frac{1}{30}E^2+\frac{4}{10}a^2)\alpha_1+\frac{4}{10}L\,a\,\alpha_0 \\
\alpha_{n+2} &= \frac{-2E\alpha_n+8La^2\alpha_{n-2}+8La\alpha_{n-3}+2L\alpha_{n-4}}{(n+2)(n+1)} \forall\,n\in\left\{4,\,5,\,6,\,\dots\right\}
\end{align}
However, I wasn't really sure how to proceed from there. I am also unsure how the boundary conditions apply to finding $\alpha_0$ and $\alpha_1$.

Comment: Have a look at this Galerkin method with Hermite basis set: http://physics.ucsd.edu/students/courses/spring2013/physics142/Labs/FinalProjects/tunneling.pdf